# Converting attribute-based xml to json in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json, xml, xpath, xquery

I am using a routine from https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/ to convert from XML stored in an XML-column in a table to json (to be served over ajax)

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.FlattenedJSON') IS NOT NULL
   DROP FUNCTION dbo.FlattenedJSON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FlattenedJSON (@XMLResult XML)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @JSONVersion NVARCHAR(MAX), @Rowcount INT

    SELECT @JSONVersion = '', @rowcount=COUNT(*) 
    FROM @XMLResult.nodes('/root/*') x(a)

    SELECT @JSONVersion = @JSONVersion +
           STUFF((SELECT TheLine 
                  FROM 
                      (SELECT ',
    {'+
      STUFF((SELECT ',"'+COALESCE(b.c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(255)'),'')+'":"'+
       REPLACE( --escape tab properly within a value
         REPLACE( --escape return properly
           REPLACE( --linefeed must be escaped
             REPLACE( --backslash too
               REPLACE(COALESCE(b.c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),''),--forwardslash
               '\', '\\'),   
              '/', '\/'),   
          CHAR(10),'\n'),   
         CHAR(13),'\r'),   
       CHAR(09),'\t')   
     +'"'   
     FROM x.a.nodes('*') b(c) 
     FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())
[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')+'}'
   FROM @XMLResult.nodes('/root/*') x(a)
   ) JSON(theLine)
  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)' )
,1,1,'')
IF @Rowcount>1 RETURN '['+@JSONVersion+']'
RETURN @JSONVersion
```

It works nicely when the XML is

```
<product>
...
    <height>123</height>
    <width>234</width>
</product>
```

returning this result:

```
{..."height":"123","width","234"}
```

But another supplier delivers data in this format

```
<product>
    <int name="height">123</int>
    <int name="width">234</int>
    <str name="colour">red</str>
 ...
 </product>
```

which returns this result instead:

```
{"int":"123","int":"234","str":"red"}
```

which is not useful. Can a routine be made similar to the one above for XML in this format?

Some attributes are arrays

```
<arr name="images">
    <str>image1.jpg</str>
    <str>image2.jpg</str>
    <str>image3.jpg</str>
</arr>
```

but I can live without those.

Comment: what if you replace row 17 with
    STUFF((SELECT ',"'+COALESCE(b.c.value(**@name**,'NVARCHAR(255)'),'')+'":"'+ etc ... 
that is using the name attribute ?
This should produce the desired output for document of the second form.
Stil not working for the array version

Comment: Probably missing something simple, but I'm getting this error: @name must be declared. If I put it in single quotes, it compiled, but returned null.

Comment: Have you considered writing C# clr on SQL which will make json?

Comment: No, if a function in sql can do the one conversion, then it should be possible for the other too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if this is still an open question, but I want to offer [FLOWR-queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery) for your rescue:

The whole approach is a fully inlineable and can be placed within a function as a single call.

In this table there is one example of each format:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<product>
    <colour>red</colour>
    <height>123</height>
    <width>234</width>
</product>')
,(N'<product>
    <int name="height">123</int>
    <int name="width">234</int>
    <str name="colour">red</str>
</product>');
```

--the CTE *transformed* will use a FLOWR query to transform the XML so that both look the same: One node would look like this: `<nd name="colour" type="unknown">red</nd>`.

```
WITH transformed AS
(
    SELECT ID,
    YourXml.query
    (N'
        <product>
        {
        for $nd in /product/*
        return 
        if (empty($nd/@name)) then
            <nd name="{local-name($nd)}" type="unknown">{$nd/text()}</nd>
        else
            <nd name="{$nd/@name}" type="{local-name($nd)}">{$nd/text()}</nd>
        }
        </product>  
    ') AS newXml
    FROM @tbl
)
```

--the select will return the json

```
SELECT t1.ID, N'{"' + 
               STUFF(
               (
                SELECT N'","' 
                      + nd.value(N'@name',N'nvarchar(max)')
                      + N'":"'  
                      + nd.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
                FROM transformed AS t2 
                CROSS APPLY  t2.newXml.nodes(N'/product/nd') AS A(nd)
                WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') + N'"}'
FROM transformed AS t1
GROUP BY ID
```

the result:

```
ID  JSON
1   {"colour":"red","height":"123","width":"234"}
2   {"height":"123","width":"234","colour":"red"}
```